# Python Pandas: Wide format to long format but differently - similar to reverse dummy columns

Tags: python, pandas, stack

[download the data from this link](https://app.box.com/s/1kqrgh17tq36fbm9myej860yzxfm70l0)

[input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tawEt.png)

```
   Product  | Price | CS_Medium | CS_Small | SC_A | SC_B |   SC_C
0   R123    |  1.18 |   0.15    |          |      |      |   0.38
1   R234    |  0.23 |           |  (0.03)  | 0.04 |      |    0.05
```

Sum_values are sum of all the values for a particular combination of CS and SC

I spent 1.5 days and could not convert it. used stack, transpose and groupby, but nothing worked. Started coding 10 days back and new to coding, please help. Please see the pictures, I could not paste tables properly in the text area.

[output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2MM8.png)

```
   Product      CS SC  Price SUM_values
0     R123  Medium  A   1.18       0.15
1     R123  Medium  B   1.18       0.15
2     R123  Medium  C   1.18       0.54
3     R123   Small  A   1.18          -
4     R123   Small  B   1.18          -
5     R123   Small  C   1.18       0.38
6     R234  Medium  A   0.23       0.04
7     R234  Medium  B   0.23          -
8     R234  Medium  C   0.23       0.05
9     R234   Small  A   0.23       0.01
10    R234   Small  B   0.23     (0.03)
11    R234   Small  C   0.23       0.05
```

Comment: I there a reason you can't include the data in the post?

Comment: Added the data in the link and in the picture, I don't know how to include as a text.

Comment: Thanks PiRSquared, Scott and Wen for your answers. How do I automate that instead of hard coding the column names. Only hard coded name is SUM_values. This transformation is part of an automated long process and I do not get any chance to see the name of the columns. Only think I know is that in the input table column names have "_" separating column name with column levels. For example in SC_A, SC_B; I know that before "_" is column name (SC) and after underscore is column levels (A, B and C).

Comment: I've updated my post with a general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

Less obvious but no hardcoded values.

```
from itertools import product

d_ = df.set_index('Product')
prc = d_.pop('Price')

d_.columns = d_.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

c = d_.columns
l0 = c.levels[0]
l1 = c.levels[1]
b0 = c.labels[0]
b1 = c.labels[1]

r0 = range(len(l0))
ptups = list(product(*(l1[b1][b0 == i] for i in r0)))

midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(x,) + t for x in l0 for t in ptups],
    names=['key'] + l0.tolist()
)
n = midx.nlevels

_d = d_[[(x0, x1) for x0, y1 in zip(l0, zip(*ptups)) for x1 in y1]]
_d.columns = midx
_d = _d.stack(list(range(1, n)), dropna=False)

_d.fillna(0).sum(1).where(_d.notna().any(1)).reset_index(name='SUM_values')

   Product      CS SC  SUM_values
0     R123  Medium  A        0.15
1     R123  Medium  B        0.15
2     R123  Medium  C        0.53
3     R123   Small  A         NaN
4     R123   Small  B         NaN
5     R123   Small  C        0.38
6     R234  Medium  A        0.04
7     R234  Medium  B         NaN
8     R234  Medium  C        0.05
9     R234   Small  A        0.01
10    R234   Small  B       -0.03
11    R234   Small  C        0.02
```

---

#### Option 2

Using `defaultdict` and a `for` loop

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for c in df.columns:
    k, *v = c.split('_')
    if v:
        d[k].append(v[0])

pd.DataFrame([
    [row.Product, c, s, row.Price, row[f'CS_{c}'], row[f'SC_{s}']]
    for i, row in df.iterrows()
    for c in d['CS'] for s in d['SC']
], columns='Product CS SC Price CS_v SC_v'.split()).assign(
    SUM_values=lambda d: d.CS_v.add(d.SC_v, fill_value=0)
).drop(['CS_v', 'SC_v'], 1)

   Product      CS SC  Price  SUM_values
0     R123  Medium  A   1.18        0.15
1     R123  Medium  B   1.18        0.15
2     R123  Medium  C   1.18        0.53
3     R123   Small  A   1.18         NaN
4     R123   Small  B   1.18         NaN
5     R123   Small  C   1.18        0.38
6     R234  Medium  A   0.23        0.04
7     R234  Medium  B   0.23         NaN
8     R234  Medium  C   0.23        0.05
9     R234   Small  A   0.23        0.01
10    R234   Small  B   0.23       -0.03
11    R234   Small  C   0.23        0.02
```

---

### Option 3

Use `defaultdict`, `itertools.product`, and `lookup`

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for c in df.columns:
    k, *v = c.split('_')
    if v:
        d[k].append(v[0])

d = {**df[['Product']].to_dict('l'), **d}

d_ = df.set_index('Product')

ndf = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(d.keys(), zip(*product(*d.values())))))

cs = pd.Series(d_.lookup(ndf.Product, ndf.CS.radd('CS_')), ndf.index)
sc = pd.Series(d_.lookup(ndf.Product, ndf.SC.radd('SC_')), ndf.index)

ndf['SUM_values'] = cs.add(sc, fill_value=0)
ndf[['Product', 'CS', 'SC', 'SUM_values']]

   Product      CS SC  SUM_values
0     R123  Medium  A        0.15
1     R123  Medium  B        0.15
2     R123  Medium  C        0.53
3     R123   Small  A         NaN
4     R123   Small  B         NaN
5     R123   Small  C        0.38
6     R234  Medium  A        0.04
7     R234  Medium  B         NaN
8     R234  Medium  C        0.05
9     R234   Small  A        0.01
10    R234   Small  B       -0.03
11    R234   Small  C        0.02
```

Comment: ptups = list(product(*(l1[b1][b0 == i] for i in r0))). In option 1, the above line getting error for product. the error is "product is not defined." I tried to define product as tuple but that did not work.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the import.

Comment: No problem, this is very helpful, now everything is working, will scale it for 30-40 columns I have. Only change here is I replaced _d.notna() with _d.notnull(). This change is done because I was getting error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'notna'."  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you can do it this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':['R123','R234'],
                        'Price':[1.18,0.23],
                        'CS_Medium':[.15, np.nan],
                        'CS_Small':[np.nan, -0.03],
                        'SC_A':[np.nan,0.04],
                        'SC_B':[np.nan,np.nan],
                        'SC_C':[0.38,0.05]})

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').str[-1]

(df.melt(['Product','Medium','Small','Price'],value_name='Values_1', var_name='SC')
  .melt(['Product','SC','Price','Values_1'],value_name='Values_2',var_name='CS')
  .set_index(['Product','CS','SC','Price'])
  .sum(axis=1)
  .reset_index(name='SUM_Values')
  .sort_values(by=['Product','CS','SC']))
```

Output:

```
   Product      CS SC  Price  SUM_values
0     R123  Medium  A   1.18        0.15
2     R123  Medium  B   1.18        0.15
4     R123  Medium  C   1.18        0.53
6     R123   Small  A   1.18         NaN
8     R123   Small  B   1.18         NaN
10    R123   Small  C   1.18        0.38
1     R234  Medium  A   0.23        0.04
3     R234  Medium  B   0.23         NaN
5     R234  Medium  C   0.23        0.05
7     R234   Small  A   0.23        0.01
9     R234   Small  B   0.23       -0.03
11    R234   Small  C   0.23        0.02
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `wide_to_long`

```
l=['Product','Price']

s1=l+df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('SC')].tolist()
s2=l+df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('CS')].tolist()


v1=pd.wide_to_long(df[s1],['SC'],i=['Product','Price'],j='SCKey',sep='_',suffix='\\w+').reset_index(level=2)

v2=pd.wide_to_long(df[s2],['CS'],i=['Product','Price'],j='CSKey',sep='_',suffix='\\w+').reset_index(level=2)

v=v1.join(v2,how='outer').reset_index()
v.assign(SUM_values=v.SC.add(v.CS,fill_value=0))
Out[66]: 
   Product  Price SCKey    SC   CSKey    CS  SUM_values
0     R123   1.18     A   NaN  Medium  0.15        0.15
1     R123   1.18     A   NaN   Small   NaN         NaN
2     R123   1.18     B   NaN  Medium  0.15        0.15
3     R123   1.18     B   NaN   Small   NaN         NaN
4     R123   1.18     C  0.38  Medium  0.15        0.53
5     R123   1.18     C  0.38   Small   NaN        0.38
6     R234   0.23     A  0.04  Medium   NaN        0.04
7     R234   0.23     A  0.04   Small -0.03        0.01
8     R234   0.23     B   NaN  Medium   NaN         NaN
9     R234   0.23     B   NaN   Small -0.03       -0.03
10    R234   0.23     C  0.05  Medium   NaN        0.05
11    R234   0.23     C  0.05   Small -0.03        0.02
```

Detail Info :

```
v1
Out[38]: 
              SCKey    SC
Product Price            
R123    1.18      A   NaN
        1.18      B   NaN
        1.18      C  0.38
R234    0.23      A  0.04
        0.23      B   NaN
        0.23      C  0.05
v2
Out[39]: 
                CSKey    CS
Product Price              
R123    1.18   Medium  0.15
        1.18    Small   NaN
R234    0.23   Medium   NaN
        0.23    Small -0.03
```